# Given a geocode or geo location in US, how to find exits that are within some distance from the geo location for US?

Tags: geoprocessing

We have a need to find the geocodes of US highway exits that are within some distance from a given geocode. I do not know how to do this? Can one please direct to the right source or provide a solution to me?

Answer (score 1):

what GIS software do you have available?

It varies from software to software, but I would either do an internet search for "select attributes by location" or "buffer" and your GIS software suite name.